# Selecting UICollectionViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Problem - I'm trying to select UICollectionView cells programmatically. I looked at all of the solutions mentioned on StackOverflow, but none is working for me. Here's what I tried

What I tried -

```
                for i in 0 ..< self.categories.count {
                    if (MUser.sharedInstance.recommendations.contains(self.categories[i].name)) {
                        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
                        self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .top)
                        self.collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What isn’t working?

Comment: it doesn't sell the items

Comment: What is leading you to the conclusion that the items aren't selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call them on mainThread they will work

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     let indexPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
     self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .top)
     self.collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Just call the didSelectItem function directly

```
collectionView(colletionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
```

Comment: That doesn't work